Make_ellipse from points azimuth and range
How to calculate an ellipse in QGIS Gemotry Generator if there is a point layer with a specified azimuth and distance.

Set in Symbol parameters Gemetry Generator and Geometry Type: Polygon with this code
make_ellipse( 
project( 
    $geometry, 
    "Range", 
    radians( "azimuth" ) ) ,
"Range",
"Range" / 2 ,
"azimuth" 

)


Could you please explain, what your code does?
